# Email on predefined template via outlook C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, email-client

I have a requirement to send automated emails based on a template saved at path :

**HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/emailTemplate/emailTemplate.oft")**

I am using code below to accomplishis this, it works fine without template by using (oApp.CreateItem()), but when i use
oApp.CreateItemFromTemplate() instead of oApp.CreateItem() i get exception.

```
public static void CreateMessageWithAttachment(
          string invoiceNumber, string recipient,  string messageBody)
{

    Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.Folders folder = oApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(
                               Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts) 
                                as Outlook.Folders;
    Outlook.MailItem email = oApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(
                               HostingEnvironment.MapPath(
                                "~/Content/emailTemplate/emailTemplate.oft"), folder)
                                   as Outlook.MailItem;

    email.Recipients.Add(recipient);
    email.Subject = "Invoice # " + invoiceNumber;

    {
      string fileName = invoiceNumber.Trim();
      string filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/reports/");
      filePath = filePath + fileName + ".pdf";
      fileName += ".pdf";
      int iPosition = (int)email.Body.Length + 1;
      int iAttachType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
      Outlook.Attachment oAttach = email.Attachments.Add(
                           filePath, iAttachType, iPosition, fileName);
    }

    email.Display();
    ////..uncomment below line to SendAutomatedEmail emails atomaticallly
    ////((Outlook.MailItem)email).Send(); 
}
```

Comment: Paste the exception that you are getting.. also CreateItemFromTemplate( expects a template file) you are casting it as OutLookMailItem.. what's the filepath and name of the template file..?

Comment: the path and name of template file("~/Content/emailTemplate/emailTemplate.oft")

Comment: exception is e = {"Could not complete the operation. One or more parameter values are not valid."}  **TargetSite = {System.Object CreateItemFromTemplate(System.String, System.Object)}**

Comment: you are declaring your folder as Outlook.Folders change to Outlook.Folder the error means it's expecting ( string, object)

Comment: not able to find Outlook.Folder. It has only **Outlook.Folders**

Comment: this is how Microsoft MSDN help shows it.. I will dig deeper on my end

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5899/discussion-between-dj-kraze-and-mini)

Comment: try copying the template file to your local hard drive and running it.. it it works that means it's a Path issue and you need to be able to resolve the nework path or network share location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//use this as a example I wonder if the network path has issues being resolved what error 
//are you getting as well
"~/Content/emailTemplate/emailTemplate.oft" you need to get the relative path on the network too. replace the sample below with your values and variables.

```
private void CreateItemFromTemplate()
{
    Outlook.Folder folder =
        Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(
        Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts) as Outlook.Folder;
    Outlook.MailItem mail =
        Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(
        @""~/Content/emailTemplate/emailTemplate.oft", folder) as Outlook.MailItem;
    mail.Subject = "Congratulations";
    mail.Save();
}
```